# Multi attach Laravel from ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, laravel, eloquent, laravel-sanctum

I have a litte problem inputting data from client to server, where the value does not match and has an error.
I want to add data using a pivot table with attach but the value I get does not match I tried several ways but failed.
What I want after creating the document data then attach the user according to what has been inputted in the client.

**The problem**

Just want to take id from client for pivot maybe like that:

```
$document->sent_to()->attach($request->users);
```

here's the code I've made:

**Server**

```
    try {
        $document = Document::create([
            'udin' => $request['udin'],
            'slug' => $uuid,
            'status' => self::$active,
        ]);
       
        $document->sent_to()->attach($request['users']);

        return ResponseFormatter::success(
             DocumentResource::collection([$document])[0],
             self::$saved
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return ResponseFormatter::error([
            'message' => self::$wrong,
            'error' => $e->errors(),
        ], self::$failed, 500);
    }
```

**Client**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

First, I manipulate data [client-side](https://prnt.sc/16az1t1)

Then on the server I use implode() with separator ,

```
explode(",", $request->users);
```

After that I do looping for get the result what i want

**UPDATED**

before sending the data I enter the data into the JSON.stringify() function
then in the serve section I use json_decode()